# AngularJS data is not set in $scope, return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I created a factory which has list of functions those get called on state change.
I am calling dtoResource.rc1Step1DTO() on page load.
Function executed but when I see result in console it returns undefined.
[image]

Below is code autoQuoteCtrl.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

 angular
    .module("autoQuote")
        //Do initalization on page load
       .run(["$log","$rootScope","$state","dtoResource",function($log,$rootScope,$state,dtoResource) { 
          $log.info('Post DTO on page load.');
          //$log.info("Value="+ angular.element('#save_quote_email').val());
          $rootScope.postAutoQuoteObj = dtoResource.rc1Step1DTO();
          console.log($rootScope);
          $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            if (fromState.name === "") { 
              // The initial transition comes from "root", which uses the empty string as a name.
               //$log.info("Value="+ angular.element('#a1').val());
            }
          });
        }])
        // Post DTO
        .controller("autoQuoteCtrl", ["$log","$scope","dtoResource","$http","$state", function($log,$scope,dtoResource,$http,$state) {
        $scope.onSubmit = function() {
             // add check if valid
             //call function from your service, and do something with it
             dtoResource.rc1Step1DTO();
            //console.log($scope);
             $log.info('hi, I was invoked on form submit');
                $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : '/rc1/getQuestions/'+$state.current.name,
                data: {'name': 'praveen', 'email': 'test@gmail.com'},
                    headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;'
                    }
                //data    : { dtoObj: '' }, // pass in data as strings //JSON.stringify(prepareAutoQuoteDTO.postAutoQuoteObj)
               // headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
            })
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (!data.success) {

                } else {
                  // if successful, bind success message to message
                  //$scope.message = data.message;
                  //$state.go('step2');
                }
            });
        };            
    }]);  

}());
```

dtoResource.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("autoQuote")
        .factory("dtoResource",["$resource",dtoResource]);

    function dtoResource($resource)
    {
        console.log('here in dto process.');
        var prepareAutoQuoteDTO = {        
        postAutoQuoteObj         : getAutoQuoteObject(),  
        initializeDriverObj: function(){
            var driverLocObj           = new Driver();
            driverLocObj.PersonInfo    = new PersonInfo();
            driverLocObj.DriverLicense = new DriverLicense();
            driverLocObj.Incident      = new Incident();
            return driverLocObj;
       },
       initializeAppInfo: function(){
           var appInfoLocObj           = new ApplicationInfo();
           appInfoLocObj.Discount      = new Discount();
           return appInfoLocObj;
       },
       /*
       * Initialize Vehicle object for autoQuoteDTO.js
       */
       initializeVehicleObj: function(){
           var vehicleLocObj = new Vehicle();
           return vehicleLocObj;
       },
       /*
       * store session info
       */
       rc1Step1DTO: function(){
            var emailId = 'test@gmail.com';//angular.element('#save_quote_email').val();
            if (typeof emailId  !== "undefined" && emailId && emailId != '' && emailId != 'Email Address'){
                var email           = new Email();
                email.EmailTypeCd   = 'PRIMARY';
                email.EmailAddress  = emailId;
                this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo =     this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo || new Contact();
                this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails = [];
                this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails.push(email);
            }
        }
    };
    return prepareAutoQuoteDTO;
}



function getAutoQuoteObject()
    {
        var autoQuoteObject = new autoQuote(); autoQuoteObject.DriverVehicleInfo = new DriverVehicleInfo(); autoQuoteObject.DriverVehicleInfo.Vehicles = []; autoQuoteObject.DriverVehicleInfo.Drivers = []; autoQuoteObject.ApplicationInfo = new ApplicationInfo(); autoQuoteObject.ApplicationInfo.Discount = new Discount(); autoQuoteObject.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo = new GeneralPartyInfo(); autoQuoteObject.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo = new Contact(); autoQuoteObject.ApplicationInfo.MostRecentInsurance = new MostRecentInsurance(); autoQuoteObject.RequestedCoverage = new RequestedCoverage(); autoQuoteObject.RequestedCoverage.PolicyCoverage = new PolicyCoverage(); autoQuoteObject.RequestedCoverage.PolicyCoverage.Coverages = []; autoQuoteObject.RequestedCoverage.VehicleCoverage = []; autoQuoteObject.SessionInfo = new SessionInfo(); return autoQuoteObject;
    }
function autoQuote()
    {
        this.DriverVehicleInfo = null; this.ApplicationInfo = null; this.RequestedCoverage = null; this.SessionInfo = null; 
    }

function DriverVehicleInfo()
    {
        this.Drivers = []; this.Vehicles = []; this.DriverVehicleUsages = []; }; var Driver = function(){this.ID = null, this.PersonInfo = null, this.DriverRelationshipToApplicant = null, this.DriverRelationshipToApplicantCd = null, this.DriverLicense = null, this.DriverDetails = [], this.Incident = null, this.IsValid = false}; var PersonInfo = function(){this.FirstName = null, this.Initial = null, this.LastName = null, this.Suffix = null, this.SSN = null, this.GenderCd = null, this.BirthDate = null, this.MaritalStatusCd = null, this.OccupationClassCd = null, this.YearsOccupation = null, this.HighestEducation = null, this.AgeInYears = 0, this.SpouseLicenseStatus = null}; var DriverLicense = function(){this.AgeLicense = null, this.USLicenseStatus = null, this.DriverLicenseNumber = null, this.StateProvCd = null}; var DriverDetail = function(){this.DriverDetailCd = null, this.DriverDetailValue = null, this.DriverDetailDate = null}; var Incident = function(){this.ClaimAccidentsCount = null, this.ViolationsCount = null, this.HasLicenseBeenRevoked = null, this.LicenseSuspensionRevokedDate = null, this.HasRequiredCourtOrderedFinancial = null, this.ClaimAccidents = [], this.Violations = [], this.DUIs = []}; var DUI = function(){this.DateOfDUI = null, this.OtherValues = []}; var ClaimAccident = function(){this.Id = null, this.ClaimAccidentCd = null, this.displayText = null, this.ClaimAccidentDate = null, this.DateDisplayText = null, this.Comprehensive = null, this.Collision = null, this.RentalReimbursement = null, this.MedicalPayment = null, this.PayToOtherParty = null, this.IsInjury = null, this.IsPropertyDamage = null}; var Violation = function(){this.Id = null, this.ViolationCd = null, this.ViolationDate = null, this.displayText = null}; var Vehicle = function(){this.ID = null, this.VehicleHaveVin = false, this.VehicleIdentificationNumber = null, this.VehicleYear = null, this.VehicleMake = null, this.VehicleModel = null, this.VehicleSubModel = null, this.AntiLockBrakeCd = null, this.AntiTheftDeviceCd = null, this.VehicleUseCd = null, this.NumDaysDrivenPerWeek = null, this.DistanceOneWay = null, this.EstimatedAnnualDistance = null, this.OwnershipCd = null, this.RegistrationStateProvCd = null, this.VehIdentificationNumber = null, this.IsCustomizedOrAltered = null, this.OriginalVehicleCost = null, this.IsValid = false, this.VehicleType = null, this.VehicleVinStub = null, this.ShowVehicleAntiLockBrakeInfo = false, this.VehicleCost = null, this.ShowVehicleCost = false, this.DaytimeLights = null}; var DriverVehicleUsage = function(){this.DriverIDRef = null, this.VehicleIDRef = null, this.Usage = null}; var ApplicationInfo = function(){this.GeneralPartyInfo = null, this.Discount = null, this.MostRecentInsurance = null, this.ConsumerContactAuth = null, this.ConsumerInfoAuthorization = null, this.ConsumerContactMobileAuth = null}; var GeneralPartyInfo = function(){this.MainApplicantDriverIDRef = null, this.Address = null, this.PreviousAddress = null, this.ContactInfo = null, this.ResidenceInfo = null, this.ListedVehiclesRegisteredTo = null, this.CreditScore = 0}; var AddressInfo = function(){this.Address = null, this.City = null, this.State = null, this.PostalCode = null, this.County = null}; var PreviousAddress = function(){this.Address = null, this.City = null, this.State = null, this.PostalCode = null, this.County = null}; var Contact = function(){this.Phones = [], this.Emails = []}; var Email = function(){this.EmailTypeCd = null, this.EmailAddress = null}; var Phone = function(){this.PhoneTypeCd = null, this.PhoneNumber = null}; var Residence = function(){this.LengthAtCurrentAddressCd = null, this.ResidenceTypeCd = null, this.NumberDriversInHouseHold = null, this.VehiclesRegistedToInsured = null, this.DriverResidentsFromFL = null, this.CityLimits = null}; var Discount = function(){this.ResidentialInsurancePolicy = null, this.OwnBoat = null, this.OwnMotorCycle = null, this.IsAAAMember = null}; var MostRecentInsurance = function(){this.HasAutoInsurance = null, this.InsuranceCompanyName = null, this.CurrentInsurancePaying = null, this.LengthWithCurrentInsuranceCd = null, this.BodilyInjuryLiabilityLimit = null, this.LengthContinuouslyInsuredCd = null, this.ExpirationDate = null, this.InsuranceCanceledForNonPay = null, this.ClaimDeniedDueToFraud = null}; var RequestedCoverage = function(){this.EffectiveDate = null, this.StateCd = null, this.PolicyCoverage = null, this.VehiclesCoverage = []}; var PolicyCoverage = function(){this.Coverages = []}; var Coverage = function(){this.CoverageCd = null, this.CoverageValue = null}; var VehicleCoverage = function(){this.IsValid = false, this.VehicleIDRef = null, this.Coverages = []}; var SessionInfo = function(){this.SessionId = '', this.SecurityToken = '', this.Zip = '', this.StateCode = '', this.PageName = '', this.PageTheme = '', this.CarrierId = - 1, this.ReturnedCarrierTypes = null, this.CoveragePackage = '', this.UseExistingSession = false, this.QuoteStatus = '', this.SID = - 1, this.SRC = null, this.SRC_QCP = null, this.Referral = null, this.ClientIP = null, this.BrowserType = null, this.CLK = 0, this.QTR = '', this.CCID = '', this.AFF = '', this.PreviousSessionId = '', this.IgnoreErrors = false, this.RetrieveSource = '', this.PreviousPageName = ''
    }

}());
```

Am I missing something, please suggest to get this fix.

Comment: `rc1Step1DTO()` interesting name for a function, easy to remember:))

Comment: are you sure that `if (typeof emailId  !== "undefined" && emailId...` is not failing?

Comment: no, its not failing.

Comment: prepareAutoQuoteDTO is going to be big json. which has many nodes. and I want this data in $scope. So that could access anywhere in application.

Comment: am I doing correct in dtoResource function?

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here:

```
$rootScope.postAutoQuoteObj = dtoResource.rc1Step1DTO();
```

But your rc1Step1DTO function is not returning anything so how postAutoQuoteObj can be anything else than undefined?

Comment: Above code placed inside dtoResource() function is taken from jquery. it was working in jquery, I am trying to do the same in angualrjs. but stuck here.